# Need guidance on how to deal with review of flagged posts

Tags: support, review-queues

I have recently gone over 2,000 rep, which means I can review flagged posts.

I can barely understand some posts, and editing them to relevance is beyond me, but possibly not beyond some of the site's gurus.  I have been hitting "Skip" too often.  Guidance?

Some answers would be OK, even useful, as comments, but should not be answers.  Sometimes they are answers because the user does not have enough rep to comment. Sometimes they are just lazy answers.  However, converting such answers to comments is not within my power.  Can I recommend conversion to a comment, and if so, how?

Comment: Which review queues are you talking about? Low quality posts?

Comment: @curiousdanni Yes, LQPs. (Reviewing and tweaking posts that someone else has already edited is usually easy.)

Comment: Well I can only say that I recommend deletion for 90% of the posts in the LQ queue...

Comment: With Low-Quality Post entries that are the work of first-time posters, I try point out the problem to the poster (in a comment) and to encourage the poster either to improve the answer—if it really is an answer—by adding some supporting documentation, or to avoid posting comments as answers, if it's really just a comment. In the latter instance, more often than not, the poster doesn't have the reputation required to leave comments on other people's posts. In that case, I urge the poster to be patient and to post only real answers in answer boxes. But misplaced comments should be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only mods can convert answers to comments and, though they do so at times, it is rare. If you genuinely feel that this answer would be a useful comment and that the benefit to the site would outweigh the encouragement to this and other low-rep users to post comments in the answer box, you should flag it yourself, "in need of moderator intervention", and recommend conversion. But most 'not an answer' flags result in deletion; if the user perseveres for a few days, he will presumably gain enough rep to re-post as a comment.